# Merging GeoDataFrames - TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Point'

Tags: pandas, insert, geopandas

I have a dataframe whose one of the columns has a Series of shapely Points and another one in which I have a Series of Polygons.

```
df.head()

                    

     hash number                               street unit  \
2024459  283e04eca5c4932a     SN  AVENIDA DOUTOR SEVERIANO DE ALMEIDA  NaN   
2024460  1a92a1c3cba7941a    485  AVENIDA DOUTOR SEVERIANO DE ALMEIDA  NaN   
2024461  837341c45de519a3    475  AVENIDA DOUTOR SEVERIANO DE ALMEIDA  NaN   

            city  district region   postcode  id                     geometry  
2024459  Jaguari       NaN     RS  97760-000 NaN  POINT (-54.69445 -29.49421)  
2024460  Jaguari       NaN     RS  97760-000 NaN  POINT (-54.69445 -29.49421)  
2024461  Jaguari       NaN     RS  97760-000 NaN  POINT (-54.69445 -29.49421)

poly_df.head()
                                          centroids                                           geometry
0   POINT (-29.31067315122428 -54.64176359828149)  POLYGON ((-54.64069 -29.31161, -54.64069 -29.3...
1   POINT (-29.31067315122428 -54.63961783106958)  POLYGON ((-54.63854 -29.31161, -54.63854 -29.3...
2  POINT (-29.31067315122428 -54.637472063857665)  POLYGON ((-54.63640 -29.31161, -54.63640 -29.3...
```

I'm checking if the Point belongs to the Polygon and inserting the Point object into the cell of the second dataframe. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   
  File "/tmp/ipykernel_4771/1967309101.py", line 1, in <module>
    df.loc[idx, 'centroids'] = poly_mun.loc[ix, 'centroids']

  File ".local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 692, in __setitem__
    iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value, self.name)

  File ".local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1599, in _setitem_with_indexer
    self.obj[key] = infer_fill_value(value)

  File ".local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/missing.py", line 516, in infer_fill_value
    val = np.array(val, copy=False)

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Point'
```

I'm using the following command line:

```
df.loc[idx, 'centroids'] = poly_df.loc[ix, 'centroids']
```

I have already tried `at` as well.

Thanks

Comment: please provide a fully reproducible example: a DataFrame constructor with a few Points objects in it

Comment: @mozway is ti fine right now?

Comment: not really this is still text. Best would be to have a full code that one can copy paste to get the exact objects

Comment: @mozway the whole problem is related to the command line `df.loc[idx, 'centroids'] = poly_df.loc[ix, 'centroids']`. If you try to insert a Point object to a Pandas column you'll get the same error.

Comment: Even more importantly we need the full set of code leading up to the error and the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback). For example, we don’t know what idx is. See the guide to creating a [mre] - it’s much harder for us to debug without one. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelDelgado thanks for the comment. I' just added the full traceback.

Comment: we just need the reproducible object(s) now ;) something like `from shapely import ... ; df = pd.DataFrame({'centroid': [Point(...), Point(...)]})` I'll let you fill in the blanks

Comment: Also tracebacks always start with `Traceback (most recent call last)` - can you add the full output?

Comment: But this is helpful. Now we still need the code used to generate all the pieces causing the error. If you specify ‘df['centroid'] = df['centroid'].astype('object')` before the line you’re using does that help?

Comment: Generally though this seems like a problem for geopandas.sjoin

Comment: @MichaelDelgado `df` has no column called 'centroid' I'm using `loc` to create this new column.

Comment: Oh! This is why we need the code. You can’t do that :) I’d try `gpd.sjoin(df, poly_df)`. See the geopandas docs on sjoin for options and details.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado cool, thanks! But as it is apparent in the dataframe printing above, I have no common column to join both dataframes. I'm checking the intersection between the polygons and inserting the centroid point to another dataframe.

Comment: That’s what sjoin does -it’s a spatial join using the polygons

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I'll check it out! Thank you so much!

Comment: @MichaelDelgado you were right. I just trasnformed both dataframes in geodataframes and applied `gpd.sjoin(df, poly_df)` and I've got the expected result. Please, post the answer that I'll accept as the correct one. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a new column in pandas with a shapely geometry using loc:

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd, shapely.geometry

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'mycol': [1, 2, 3]})

In [3]: df.loc[0, "centroid"] = shapely.geometry.Point([0, 0])
/Users/mikedelgado/opt/miniconda3/envs/rhodium-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1642: ShapelyDeprecationWarning: The array interface is deprecated and will no longer work in Shapely 2.0. Convert the '.coords' to a numpy array instead.
  self.obj[key] = infer_fill_value(value)
/Users/mikedelgado/opt/miniconda3/envs/rhodium-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/missing.py:550: FutureWarning: The input object of type 'Point' is an array-like implementing one of the corresponding protocols (`__array__`, `__array_interface__` or `__array_struct__`); but not a sequence (or 0-D). In the future, this object will be coerced as if it was first converted using `np.array(obj)`. To retain the old behaviour, you have to either modify the type 'Point', or assign to an empty array created with `np.empty(correct_shape, dtype=object)`.
  val = np.array(val, copy=False)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df.loc[0, "centroid"] = shapely.geometry.Point([0, 0])

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/rhodium-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:716, in _LocationIndexer.__setitem__(self, key, value)
    713 self._has_valid_setitem_indexer(key)
    715 iloc = self if self.name == "iloc" else self.obj.iloc
--> 716 iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value, self.name)

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/rhodium-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1642, in _iLocIndexer._setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value, name)
   1639     self.obj[key] = empty_value
   1641 else:
-> 1642     self.obj[key] = infer_fill_value(value)
   1644 new_indexer = convert_from_missing_indexer_tuple(
   1645     indexer, self.obj.axes
   1646 )
   1647 self._setitem_with_indexer(new_indexer, value, name)

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/rhodium-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/missing.py:550, in infer_fill_value(val)
    548 if not is_list_like(val):
    549     val = [val]
--> 550 val = np.array(val, copy=False)
    551 if needs_i8_conversion(val.dtype):
    552     return np.array("NaT", dtype=val.dtype)

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'Point'
```

Essentially, pandas doesn't know how to interpret a point object, and so creates a float column with NaNs, and then can't handle the point. This might get fixed in the future, but you're best off explicitly defining the column as object dtype:

```py
In [27]: df['centroid'] = None

In [28]: df['centroid'] = df['centroid'].astype(object)

In [29]: df
Out[29]:
   mycol centroid
0      1     None
1      2     None
2      3     None

In [30]: df.loc[0, "centroid"] = shapely.geometry.Point([0, 0])
/Users/mikedelgado/opt/miniconda3/envs/rhodium-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py:304: ShapelyDeprecationWarning: The array interface is deprecated and will no longer work in Shapely 2.0. Convert the '.coords' to a numpy array instead.
  applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)

In [31]: df
Out[31]:
   mycol     centroid
0      1  POINT (0 0)
1      2         None
2      3         None
```

That said, joining two GeoDataFrames with polygons and points based on whether the points are in the polygons certainly sounds like a job for [`geopandas.sjoin`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin.html):

```py
union = gpd.sjoin(polygon_df, points_df, op='contains')
```